# A way to exclude Jekyll from some pages on Github?

Tags: github, jekyll

[I have a GitHub Pages site](https://github.com/alinuxlover/alinuxlover) and was wondering: is there any way to add Jekyll to it, but exclude a few files? I would not like it to render on the index file, how would I achieve that? Thanks,
ALinuxLover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to make use of the exclude directive in your_config.yml file.

Have a look at [Jekyll's global configurables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#global-configuration).

> Exclude directories and/or files from the conversion. These exclusions
>   are relative to the site's source directory and cannot be outside the
>   source directory.

To be more clear, just open your config file and add this line

```
exclude: [index.html, folder]
```

By doing this your index.html(In root directory: same as config directory) file will not going to generate by Jekyll. You can also exclude any `folder` if you want.